# C/C++ Memory Leak (Using PCRE)

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, pcre

```
// Returns a list of topic numbers found on the page
vector<string> findTopics(char* rData, int rDataLen) {
    pcre *re;
    const char *error;
    int erroffset;
    re = pcre_compile(
        "topic/([0-9]+)",   /* the pattern */
        0,          /* default options */
        &error,         /* for error message */
        &erroffset,     /* for error offset */
        NULL);          /* use default character tables */

    if(re == NULL) {
    printf("Couldn't compile regex (%s)", error);
        //  exit(-1):
    }

    int regOf[2];
    vector<string> topics;

    char *topic;
    int offset = 0;
    int rc = 1;
    // Basically a preg_match_all()
    while(true) {
        rc = pcre_exec(re, NULL, rData, rDataLen, offset, 0, regOf, sizeof(regOf));
        if (rc < 2) {
            break;
        }

        topic = new char[8];
        sprintf(topic, "%.*s\n", regOf[2*1+1] - regOf[2*1], rData + regOf[2*1]);

        topics.push_back(topic);
        offset = regOf[1];
    }

    pcre_free(re);

    return topics;
}
```

This function is supposed to fetch a list of "topics" (matching `topic/[0-9]+`) found in something specific that I parse to it, in the `rData`, and it almost works. `topics` gets filled with the topic numbers that it's supposed to.

When I debug it in Visual Studio, I get this error messages straight after the end of the function (the return): **Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'regOf' was corrupted.**

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and wondering if maybe somebody can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define regOf with 2 elements. You then pass sizeof(regOf) into the pcre_exec function, however the function asks how many items are in the array, not how many bytes in size it is. As such, the function thinks it has 8 slots to fill, it only has 2, so can run off the end of the array and corrupt memory.

Comment: It was also mentioned in another answer that has since disappeared that you should also be careful about doing that sprint into topic. As it's only 8 characters long you can at most put a 7 character string into it before that will overflow the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore to the other answers, if any of your statements between `pcre_compile` and `pcre_free` throw an exception (I see at least three of them that could do so), you leak memory.